# Developing application that represents same screen across multiple browser windows of same machine using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have to create one application that represents the same screen(sharing the state of the view/screen) across multiple browser windows of same machine using AngularJS.

During my analysis I found perhaps AngularJS is not the best technology to handle such scenarios, please find below my thoughts:

- If I open the same application in second window of the browser after
  opening it in the first one, I need to copy the full
  state(rootScope/scope/services) to other window
- If user performs some action in one window I need to update the other screen/window accordingly for which I need to use web sockets
- Complexity of scope digest cycles execution

Please suggest.

Comment: Will it be a good idea to use local storage and watch the variables of local storage???

Comment: **across multiple browser windows of same machine** by this what you mean? why do u want to open same application across multiple browser windows of same machine?

Comment: As the screen has no. of panels, so the idea is to display some panel in one window and the remaining in other

Comment: what are the data they are going to share?. browsers as in ? different browsers or different tabs in same browser?

Answer (score 2):

I faced kinda the same scenario while working on chat sessions where the user can open multiple chat windows (as popup windows) while the parent site is open. I used local storage for handling some of its scenarios. I used [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) for this.

**Note**: Make sure you are handling (deleting/updating/adding) the data properly while storing it in local storage of browser. Graceful execution is the key or else you'll end up with many bugs.

Hope it helps !